# sed string replace entire word if part of string matches but do no affect words after the string

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, pam

I've this line:

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so difok=355 abcd
```

How can I replace "difok=355" with "difok=8"?
The value 355 can be anything.
Basically replace "difok=X" with "difok=8".

I tried this:

```
sed -i '/^#/!s/difok=.*/difok=8/g' temp
```

But this replaces any text that is after "difok="

I tried:

```
sed -i '/^#/!s/\bdifok=*\b/difok=8/g' temp
```

This gives "difok=8355".

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed and extended regular expressions (`-r`):

```
sed -r -i 's/(difok=)[0-9]+/\18/' file
```

or

```
sed -r -i 's/(difok=)[^ ]+/\18/' file
```

Output:

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so difok=8 abcd
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please tell me whats the 1 doing?

Comment: `\1` repeats the part that matched inside the parenthesis `difok=`. Documentation: [5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it this way:

```
sed -i 's/difok=[^ ]*/difok=8/' temp
```

The first half of the replacement command matches `difok=` followed by any number of characters that are not spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
echo "password requisite pam_cracklib.so difok=355 abcd" |sed -E -n 's/(.* )(difok=[0-9]+)(.*)/\1difok=8\3/p'
```

Output:

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so difok=8 abcd
```